# Is there a way to know the number of key from the root on Firebase RealtimeDatabase?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase RealtimeDatabase to manage information using Json. I can get the snapshot and all the information inside with the key identifier:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("myKey").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // my code
});
```

And I don't know how I can get the childrenCount from the root "Key", I already tried using "default-rtdb" but it didn't work, nether while navigating the `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.Root` etc...

Comment: Hey Allan. Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get just the count of nodes from the Firebase Realtime Database. If you want that, you will actually have to store such a value in the database, and keep it up to date yourself.

But you *can* load all the data from any node in the database. If you want to load all data from the root, call `GetReference` without passing in a path. So: `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference().GetValueAsync()`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)